# Draw function on top of a heatmap in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I managed to display a heatmap of a series of data and now I would like to add a curve of a function on top of that same heatmap.

The data is the following

```
n   p   value
10  0.1 0.90194
10  0.2 0.814638
10  0.3 0.753783
10  0.4 0.742528
10  0.5 0.803991
10  0.6 0.830976
10  0.7 0.906513
10  0.8 0.953166
10  0.9 0.975436
10  1   0.853681
20  0.1 0.625281
20  0.2 0.623298
20  0.3 0.873965
20  0.4 1.23219
20  0.5 1.54184
20  0.6 1.75956
20  0.7 1.96547
20  0.8 1.97974
20  0.9 1.66577
20  1   1.36916
30  0.1 0.476853
30  0.2 0.793067
30  0.3 1.31858
30  0.4 1.73176
30  0.5 2.22286
30  0.6 2.62717
30  0.7 2.91953
30  0.8 2.8295
30  0.9 2.1744
30  1   1.62212
40  0.1 0.46209
40  0.2 1.03452
40  0.3 1.69294
40  0.4 2.29018
40  0.5 2.85929
40  0.6 3.41063
40  0.7 3.69093
40  0.8 3.57169
40  0.9 2.90467
40  1   1.97858
```

and the code I used is this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data_to_string <- function(data) {
    data$n = mapply(
        function(x) {
            if (0 <= x && x < 10) { return (paste0("00",toString(x))) }
            else if (10 <= x && x < 100) { return (paste0("0",toString(x))) }
            return (toString(x))
        },
        data$n
    )
    data$p = mapply(function(x) { toString(x) }, data$p)
    return (data)
}

plot_data <- function(data) {
    data$Y <- cut(data$value, breaks = c(0,1,2,3,Inf), right = FALSE)
    g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = p, y = n)) +
        geom_tile(aes(fill = Y)) +
        scale_y_discrete(labels = c(`040` = "40", `030` = "30", `020` = "20", `010` = "10")) +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn") +
        geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
        labs(fill = "Value")
    return (g)
}
values = read.csv("test_data.csv", sep = "\t", header = T)
values = data_to_string(values)
g = plot_data(values)
print(g)
```

The result of the code run on the data above is

[image]

How do I add the curve of a function on top of the heatmap? The function is just a mathematical function on the values of the x-axis. In the x-axis of the figure we see `p` (which stands for probability). I would like to draw the function `f(p) = 4/p` on top the heatmap, so that it looks something like this

[image]

It's okay if the function is plotted as a sequence of points and these in turn joined with line segments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stat_function` to add a continuous curve with your equation. Also make sure to use the right `labels` for your discrete axis like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data_to_string <- function(data) {
  data$n = mapply(
    function(x) {
      if (0 <= x && x < 10) { return (paste0("00",toString(x))) }
      else if (10 <= x && x < 100) { return (paste0("0",toString(x))) }
      return (toString(x))
    },
    data$n
  )
  data$p = mapply(function(x) { toString(x) }, data$p)
  return (data)
}

plot_data <- function(data) {
  data$Y <- cut(data$value, breaks = c(0,1,2,3,Inf), right = FALSE)
  g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = p, y = n)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = Y)) +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = rev(c("40", "30", "20", "10"))) +
    stat_function(fun = \(p) {4/p}, color = "yellow") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PRGn") +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
    labs(fill = "Value")
  return (g)
}

values = data_to_string(values)
g = plot_data(values)
print(g)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>